# Mailgun template for batch sending with recipient variables in Handlebars expression

Tags: handlebars.js, mailgun

I am trying to create a Mailgun template for batch sending, and the template needs to use a **recipient variable** within a **Handlebars** conditional to determine the language to use, like so:

```
<div>
  {{#if %recipient.eng%}}
    Hello
  {{else}}
     Bonjour
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

However, when making a POST call to create the above template, I get the error response:

```
 "message": "template parse error: Parse error on line 2:\nLexer error\nToken: Error{\"Unexpected character in expression: '%'\"}"
```

There isn't any documentation on the Mailgun site that uses batch sending with Handlebars, so it may not be possible.
Has anyone managed to successfully do this?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? What is the alternate option you used?

Answer (score 2):

Having asked the question to Mailgun support, they recently got back to me.
The conclusion is it is not possible to use **recipient variables** within **handlebars** expressions unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the participant variable to be a standard variable for the email. Note the line starting -F v:eng.

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
-F from='Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
-F to=alice@example.com \
-F to=bob@example.com \
-F recipient-variables='{"bob@example.com": {"first":"Bob", "id":1, "eng": true}, "alice@example.com": {"first":"Alice", "id": 2, "eng": false}}' \
-F v:eng='%recipient.eng%'
-F subject='Hey, %recipient.first%' \
-F text='If you wish to unsubscribe, click http://mailgun/unsubscribe/%recipient.id%'
```

You will then be able to access it using the standard variable in your handlebars template

```
<div>
  {{#if %eng%}}
    Hello
  {{else}}
     Bonjour
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. But the problem is to do with using recipient variables "with handlebar" expressions in the template. There are no handlebar expressions in your text. Mailgun have suggested it is not possible.

Comment: @GlenAu-Yeung I have expanded my answer to clarify

Comment: @thelem I am trying to use your example but it's not working. When i use `{{#if %eng%}}` in template it's not updating template in MailGun Control Panel. Throws exception.

Comment: @Dot_NETPro That sounds like it needs a new question, including the full details of what you've entered in your template and the exception thrown.